# find theta to minimize quadratic function of n variables

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm working on a continuous optimization problem and am having some trouble. Here is the problem:

**Let $ x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} $ be real values, assume $ w_{i}>0 $. Find the solution $ \theta^{*} $ that minimizes $ f(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i}\left(x_{i}-\theta\right)^{2} $.**

How would I go about solving this? I tried to use the second derivative test and found the first derivative to be $ f'(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2*w_{i}\left(-x_{i}+\theta\right) $. I used logic to reason through this and broke down what would happen if $x_i$ was positive negative and $0$. This ended up not making any sense as I reasoned that $ \theta $ should be negative infinity. Is there a reason I cant use this test for this problem? What am I doing wrong how should I approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to notice is that $f(\theta)$ can be written as $a\theta^2+b\theta+c$ for some values $a,b,c$ that depend on the $w_i,x_i$. It doesn't matter whether $x_i$ are positive or negative. All that matters is that $a$ is positive, so that the minimum exists. You can easily minimize this function by computing $f'(\theta)$ and solving for $f'(\theta)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Why would the existence of a minimum depend on whether or not $a$ is positive? Also how is this different from what I'm doing initially, since this tries to take the first derivative as well?

Comment: Additionally, when I solve this way I end up getting $\theta = x_i $. How is this possible, since isn't $ \theta star$ supposed to be a fixed number? How can it take n possible values?

Comment: Computing $f'(\theta)$ was the correct first step (whether you write $f(\theta)$ as in the problem statement or as $a\theta^2+b\theta+c$). I'm not sure how you are getting $\theta=x_i$ though, as you are correct that there is a unique value of $\theta^*$. You should be able to write your expression for $f'(\theta)$ as $2a\theta+b$. Solving for $f'(\theta^*)=0$ would then give you $\theta^*=-b/2a$.

Comment: I think the problem is that, in your expression for $f'(\theta)$, having one term of the sum be 0 is *not* the same as having the entire sum be 0. So you have to look at the entire sum, not just the individual terms of the sum